# How to increase connection pool size for Mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, connection-pooling

I am using Mongodb as database for project and i am sending 1000 requests per sec to mongodb. I got a observation that the request which are front in queue works faster as compare to request which are last in queue. I am afraid if call to mongodb increase it will consume more time. I think this i can manage using pool connection.If yes let me know how we increased pool size using python.If no suggest me any other alternative

Following are some results to find documents with field **snippetid** which i had index

**Some request which are send early**

```
db.collection.find({'snippetid': '55a0466a414353801e4ff16a'})

Time Taken 0.00563097000122

db.collection.find({'snippetid': '559417cd5217d572fa120a21'})

Time Taken 0.00330901145935
```

**Some request which are last in queue**

```
db.collection.find({'snippetid': '55a4b1d45217d5e7609e19b2'})

Time Taken 1.95499396324

db.collection.find({'snippetid': '55a059d5be98fa09168b63f9'})

Time Taken 1.96221590042
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey you can increased pool size in python using pymongo.
Syntax

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('host', port, maxPoolSize=200)
```

For more details check [link](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html)

Comment: thanx for your answer

Comment: new link: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

From the pymongo documentation for MongoClient:

> *maxPoolSize (optional): The maximum number of connections that the pool will open simultaneously. If this is set, operations will block if there are maxPoolSize outstanding connections from the pool. Defaults to 100. Cannot be 0.*

And given the signature:

```
 pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient(
     host='localhost', port=27017, document_class=dict,
     tz_aware=False, connect=True, **kwargs)
```

So adding `maxPoolSize` with your desired value within that call will set the size of the connection pool.

Note that *"nothing is free"* and this comes at a clear cost on both the client and server to maintain a large number of connections. With high request loads you might look at alternate processing methods, or at least balancing the load.

Comment: thanx for your answer